# Inconsistent display of reputation ("profile bar" vs. flair after answer)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Here is a screenshot that shows the problem. There is 6113 next to my username in the top bar, but 6103 in the flair after my answer.

[image]

I think the problem is that the value on the bar is being constantly updated as I am getting votes on my answer, but the value in the flair isn't.

Comment: This is most likely a caching issue not a bug.

Comment: In the meantime I have gotten another vote and the value in the top bar changed to 6123. I'm pretty sure this is not a caching issue since no refreshing of the page is involved in the process.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug, it's a feature!

The value in the top-bar is automatically updated when you receive upvotes using AJAX, but the values in usercards are not. Reload the page to see the most recent reputation counts in usercards.

Note the name, it's called a [usercard](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user), not your flair (which refers to the [image provided to you](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/nowearn-valuable-flair/) to post elsewhere on the internet).

Comment: What is the usefulness of this if it's a feature? Why do flairs look exactly the same as usercards if they are different?

Comment: @fish: My flair does not look the same; for one, the flair image is just that, an image, while the usercard is interactive once you [reach a certain level](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user). Mouse over my name and see it pop out.

Comment: @fish: The top-bar updates automatically because that's *your* score, only visible to you when you use the site. The question-and-answer page is there for everyone, and the scores don't update automatically there because that would put way too much strain on the server.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - we could actually do this, but it's both a) noisy and b) annoying...so it's definitely by choice we don't update everyone's reputation score everywhere.  It's just...too much updating...

Comment: @NickCraver: Cool; I imagined all the pings for long-inactive accounts would kill the cache somewhat; visit a bunch of questions that are 3 years old with plenty of answers and the server will have to look up reputation updates for all those user cards while the pages stay open.. Nice capacity you have there! :-P